# Curl request works in terminal but not in R

Tags: r, curl, httr, rcurl

The following request is succeedding in terminal:

```
curl "https://api.especiaisg1.globo/api/eventos/brasil"
  -H "authority: api.especiaisg1.globo"
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
  -H "accept: */*"
  -H "origin: https://especiais.g1.globo.com"
  -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site"
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors"
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty"
  -H "referer: https://especiais.g1.globo.com/bemestar/coronavirus/mapa-coronavirus/"
  -H "accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6"
  --compressed
```

In R it was also working well until a few days ago with the following code:

```
library(curlconverter)
library(jsonlite)

reqbr <- {'curl "https://api.especiaisg1.globo/api/eventos/brasil"
  -H "authority: api.especiaisg1.globo"
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
  -H "accept: */*"
  -H "origin: https://especiais.g1.globo.com"
  -H "sec-fetch-site: cross-site"
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors"
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty"
  -H "referer: https://especiais.g1.globo.com/bemestar/coronavirus/mapa-coronavirus/"
  -H "accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6"
  --compressed'}

resp <- make_req(straighten(reqbr))
dados_municipio <- fromJSON(toJSON(content(resp[[1]](), as="parsed"),
                                   auto_unbox = TRUE,
                                   pretty=TRUE)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select_all(~str_remove(., "docs."))
```

Now it doesn't work anymore. When I run `resp[[1]]()` the following message is given:

> ```
> Response [https://api.especiaisg1.globo/api/eventos/brasil]
>   Date: 2020-05-18 12:21
>   Status: 503
>   Content-Type: <unknown>
> <EMPTY BODY>
> ```

But as I mentioned, the request is succeeding in the terminal. Does anyone know what may be happening?

Comment: A 503 error usually suggests the service is not available. How do you know the API is working as it should?

Comment: Yes, when the request is made by the terminal it succeeds and the data is fetched.

Comment: Did you solve it ?